# Issue using rollback to a previous version of mySQL database using liquibase

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am trying to rollback to a previous version of mySQL database using liquibase. My changelog file is

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">


    <changeSet id="1" author="jessica">
        <createTable tableName="student">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="enrolled" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="2" author="jessica">
    <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
        <addColumn tableName="student">
            <column name="grade" type="decimal(3,2)" />
        </addColumn>        
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="3" author="jessica">
        <dropColumn tableName="student" columnName="enrolled"/>     
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="4" author="jessica">
        <tagDatabase tag="version 1.0.0-RELEASE"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="6" author="jessica">
        <createTable tableName="instructor">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="start_date" type="date"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="7" author="jessica">
        <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
        <tagDatabase tag="version 1.1.0-RELEASE"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="8" author="jessica">
        <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
        <dropTable tableName="instructor"/>
            <rollback changeSetId="6" changeSetAuthor="jessica"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I want to rollback to "Version 1.0.0 changesetid = "4" is where I tagged originally. changesetid ="6" is where I created the new table.  With my changeset 8 I want to rollback (drop the instructor table). Liquibase is saying it has successfully updated however, when I go into mySQL the table is still there. How can I get it rollback?

Comment: Whats the output from liquibase with CMD **UpdateSQL** instead of **Update** : http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/offline.html

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: I am using liquibase rollbackCount 6 and getting the following error now.  Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: '<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>'

SEVERE 4/2/18, 5:08 PM: liquibase: Unknown parameter: '<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unknown parameter: '<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>'
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parsePropertiesFile(Main.java:476)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:164)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)